# Dynamic property destructuring doesn't work for numbers

Tags: javascript, object, destructuring

I'm trying to remove a dynamic property from myObject (in a react project). Here is myObject:

```
myObject = {
 'property1': {},
 'property2': {},
 '3': {}
}
```

This is what I tried:

```
const {[prop]:removedItem, ... rest} = myObject;
```

the problem is that it doesn't work when `prop = '3'` ,it works when `prop = 'property1'` though.

Any ideas where I'm making a mistake?

Comment: https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-object-destructuring/

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue: https://jsfiddle.net/q7jweb9v/

Comment: @FelixKling you're right. I'm using it in React. maybe the problem is somewhere else